# JSON - Access field named '*' asterisk

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to access a JSON field that has the key `'*'`:

```
{ 
  "parse": { 
    "text": {
      "*": "text i want to access" 
    }
  }
}
```

Neither `myObject.parse.text.*` nor `myObject.parse.text[0]` works.

I have searched for an hour but haven't found any hint that an asterisk has special meaning. If I just traverse the complete tree and make String comparison with `if (key == "*")` I can retrieve the text, but I would like to access this field directly. How can I do that?

Comment: Whoever designed that JSON string should be slapped around a bit.

Comment: you get this with the wikipedia api, for example http://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Robbie_Williams&format=json&prop=text&section=0

Comment: It is not pretty, but I could see this make sense in some kind of front-end translate module. Like when a standard string should be inserted when a certain translation key does not exist for a certain language.

Answer (score 12):

```
json.parse.text["*"]
```

Yucky name for an object member.

---

Asterisks have no special meaning; it's a string like any other.

`myObject.parse.text.*` doesn't work because `*` isn't a legal JS identifier. [Dot notation requires legal identifiers for each segment.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#dot_notation)

`myObject.parse.text[0]` doesn't work because `[n]` accesses the element keyed by `n` or an array element at index `n`. There is no array in the JSON, and there is nothing with a `0` key.

There *is* an element at the key `'*'`, so `json.parse.text['*']` works.

Answer (score 5):

Try use the index operator on `parse.text`:

```
var value = object.parse.text["*"];
```

Answer (score 4):

try to use

```
var text = myObject.parse.text['*']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
var json = {"parse":
 {"text":
  {"*":"text i want to access"}
 }
}

alert(json.parse.text['*']);
```