# Json access field name "*" to Java class

Tags: java, android, json, wikipedia-api, retrofit2

Similar question in [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610191/json-access-field-named-asterisk):

I was trying to handle wikipedia api with Retrofit (moshi converter) in my android app. But I can't write java class Text with "*" as a String.

Wikipedia json request [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Android_(operating_system)&prop=text&section=2).

Edit: if it helps. Everything works except String _; since it's not "*".

```
public class Text {

  private String _;
  private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  public String get_() {
    return _;
  }

  public void set_(String _) {
    this._ = _;
  }

  public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
  }

  public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
  }
}
```

,

```
public class Section {

  private Parse parse;
  private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  public Parse getParse() {
    return parse;
  }

  public void setParse(Parse parse) {
    this.parse = parse;
  }

  public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
  }

  public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
  }

}
```

,

```
public class Parse {

  private String title;
  private Integer pageid;
  private Text text;
  private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }


  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }


  public Integer getPageid() {
    return pageid;
  }


  public void setPageid(Integer pageid) {
    this.pageid = pageid;
  }


  public Text getText() {
    return text;
  }


  public void setText(Text text) {
    this.text = text;
  }

  public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
  }

  public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
  }

}
```

Comment: Please post the code which you tried.

Comment: I simply can't create java class with "*" name to hold json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't indicate which JSON library you were using and the answer is different for each. I'm going to assume Gson.

You can use the `@SerializedName` annotation to read/write a different JSON key than what you define the field name as.

```
@SerializedName("*")
public String star;
```

This will produce JSON like `{"*": ...}` and read JSON in the same format.

Most JSON libraries in Java have some mechanism for doing this, so if you are using a library other than Gson you'll need to consult its documentation on how to change the name of a field.

Comment: I was using Moshi. Changed to Gson and answer works flawlessly

Comment: For Moshi it's `@Json(name = "*")`